# Pointer to array of char ,the value of the pointer is not an address?

Tags: c++, arrays, pointers, char

Here is a simple code I wrote.The pointer p 's value is the address of array a as we know.
However , why does the pointer s not store the address of c1?
How does it work!

```
int main(int argc, const char * argv[])
{
    int a[4] = {4,3,2,1};
    int*p = a;
    cout<<&a<<endl;//output 0x7fff5fbff8a0
    cout<<p<<endl; //oupput 0x7fff5fbff8a0

    char c1[4] = "abc";
    char *s = c1;
    cout<<&c1<<endl;//output 0x7fff5fbff894
    cout<<s<<endl; //output abc
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Your code proves, that actually it does.

Comment: That the pointer `s` does not store the address of `c1` is the wrong conclusion. Don't try to draw conclusions from formatted output. `assert(s == &c1)` is the right way to test if `s` has the address of `c1`. What you tested is if the output of the two variables through the standard streams is the same.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> why does the pointer s not store the address of c1

It does.

What you're seeing is that fact that `std::ostream::operator<<` has an overload for `char*`, treating it as a string rather than a pointer. If you use

```
printf("%p\n", s);
```

you'll see it works as expected.

Comment: In C++ you can print a pointer like `std::cout << "pointer = " << std::hex << static_cast<void*>(somePointer) << '\n';`

Comment: Yeah, but `printf()` is shorter ;-)

Comment: @TristanBrindle And more error prone.  (Although I don't know that it's shorter, either.  In both cases, you have to cast the pointer to `void*`.  In the case of `printf`, failing to do so is undefined behavior; in the case of `<<`, you get the wrong overload _if_ the pointer type is `char*`.  Otherwise, you get an implicit conversion to `void*`.  And in no case do you get undefined behavior.

Comment: @JoachimPileborg You don't need the `std::hex`, and in fact, it should be ignored, according to the standard; `std::hex` only affects the output of integral types.

Comment: @JamesKanze Don't you get an implicit conversion to `void*` with `printf()` too? (Not saying you're wrong, just never heard of it as being UB before :-) )

Comment: @TristanBrindle You're matching `...`.  The only implicit conversions here are promotions.  In practice, on a modern machine, all pointers have the same size and representation (and Posix requires this), but formally, if you pass an `int*` to `...`, and `va_arg` in the called function asks for a `void*`, you have undefined behavior.

Comment: @TristanBrindle Or to be perhaps a bit clearer: there is an implicit conversion of `T*` to `void*`, for all data types `T`, but since you're matching `...`, the compiler doesn't know that a `void*` is needed, and so doesn't apply the conversion.

Comment: @JamesKanze Never realised data pointers could have different sizes. So you're saying that an implementation with `sizeof(int*) != sizeof(void*)` could still be conforming? You learn something new every day, thanks! :-)

Comment: @TristanBrindle Of course.  In the early days of C, this was even fairly common; think of word addressed machines.  In this case, of course, while that might be the motivation behind the rules in the standard, the rule is that the type accessed using `va_arg` must be compatible with the type pushed.  On further examination of the standard, however, there are two exceptions, one of which is `void*` and `char*`.  Which interestingly enough means that `printf` doesn't need the cast in the once case you need it with `std::cout`, and needs it when `cout` doesn't.

Answer (score 1):

It called operator overloading:

```
//char* goes here:
std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream &s, const char* p)
{ 
  //print the string
}

//int* goes here:
std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream &s, const int* p)
{ 
  //print the address
}
```

if you cast the pointer to int you'll see the address.